# How to exit the loop in oracle

Tags: plsql, plsqldeveloper

```
Declare
var_cnt       number(3):=0;
begin
    loop
        update t_loan_dtl set loan_closure = 'Y' where rownum <10001;
    end loop;
end;
```

Comment: Have any of the answers help you solve your problem. If so please accept that answer. If you came-up with a different solution then post it and accept it. If your issue is not resolved update the question and indicate the remaining issue. Point being do not just leave a resolved question in an open state.  Answered questions help future questioners having the same issue.

Answer (score 9):

1. simple exit

   loop
      --do something;
      exit;
     end loop;
2. conditional exit

   loop
     --do something;
        exit when "condition";
   end loop;

3.Exit with cursor variable

```
 exit when v_cursor%notfound;
```

Answer (score 5):

You can try to use the [EXIT statament](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/exit_statement.htm)

> The EXIT statement breaks out of a loop. The EXIT statement has two
>   forms: the unconditional EXIT and the conditional EXIT WHEN. With
>   either form, you can name the loop to be exited.

Answer (score 3):

```
loop
 if(var_cnt>=10001) then
  exit;
 end if;
 var_cnt:=var_cnt+1;
end loop;
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: The code is very simple. When the variable reaches 10000, the loop exits

Answer (score 0):

You can use `EXIT` in Loop

I have used `employees` as a `Table` in the below example and `Cursor` for the operation.

```
 DECLARE
 v_employees employees%ROWTYPE;  -- declare record variable
  CURSOR c1 is SELECT * FROM employees;
 BEGIN
 OPEN c1; -- open the cursor before fetching
-- An entire row is fetched into the v_employees record
 FOR i IN 1..10 LOOP
FETCH c1 INTO v_employees;
EXIT WHEN c1%NOTFOUND;
-- process data here
END LOOP;
CLOSE c1;
END;
 /
```

Comment: What is `employees`? OP has not mentioned any such table? And why a cursor?

Comment: I have just given an Example here that How to Exit from a loop

Comment: Then you need to explicitly mention that in your answer. Else it becomes very confusing as to what your intent is!

Answer (score -1):

It entirely depends on when you want to exit the loop. If you want to run this only once, then there is no need of the loop statement, If you want to run say 100 times, then increment the counter and add an if condition to exit when the count is reached.

Comment: He asked how to exit loop explicitly, with condition met.